# MySQL substring match using regular expression; substring contain 'man' not 'woman'

Tags: mysql, regex

I have an issue while I fetch data from database using regular expression. While I search for 'man' in tags it returns tags contains 'woman' too; because its substring.

```
SELECT '#hellowomanclothing' REGEXP '^(.)*[^wo]man(.)*$'; # returns 0 correct, it contains 'woman'
SELECT '#helloowmanclothing' REGEXP '^(.)*[^wo]man(.)*$'; # returns 0 incorrect, it can contain anything other than 'woman' 
SELECT '#stylemanclothing' REGEXP '^(.)*[^wo]man(.)*$'; # returns 1 correct
```

How can I update the regular expression, when I search for 'man' it should return only the tag contains 'man' not 'woman'?

Comment: As an aside instead of writing `(.)*` *(that makes no sense)* write simply `.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant of n-dru pattern since you don't need to describe all the string:

```
SELECT '#hellowomanclothing' REGEXP '(^#.|[^o]|[^w]o)man';
```

Note: if a tag contains 'man' and 'woman' this pattern will return 1. If you don't want that Gordon Linoff solution is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
SELECT '#helloowmanclothing' REGEXP '^(.)*([^o]|[^w]o)man(.)*$'
```

In your pattern `[^wo]` stands for "one character except for w and o", while you need to exclude two consecutive characters  - w and then o.

Therefore above pattern allows for `o` before `man` only if `o` is preceeded by character other than `w`.

Comment: Here other words ends in w or o before 'man' is failing.  SELECT '#hellomanclothing' REGEXP '^(.)*[^w][^o]man(.)*$'

Comment: @San You are right, I corrected this, see my edited answer.

Comment: Why SELECT 'manclothing' REGEXP '^(.)*([^o]|[^w]o)man(.)*$' is returns 0? it should return 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two expressions.  I think `like` is sufficient:

```
SELECT ('#stylemanclothing' like '%man%' and '#stylemanclothing' not like '%woman%')
```

Although you can express this in a regular expression, this is probably the easier solution.