# Oracle SQL:Combining Multiple regexp_like statements & correct regex syntax

Tags: regex, oracle

I’m working on creating various 0/1 product flags category variables based on multiple substrings within a string field. The string values contained in the **category_description** field don’t stick to a consistent classification pattern.  Notice for each flag variable I’m using **two regexp_like** statements. The two things I’m trying to accomplish are.

1. For each category flag variable combine the two regexp_like statements into **only one regexp_like statement**
2. Thanks to n-dru's answer   https://stackoverflow.com/a/30978741/2270911 I was able to figure out how to classify men and not also classify women in a regex statement but I’m still trying to correct some of the issues I’m running to with the regex syntax.

   - Swimsuit classifying categories which actually dress suits and not swimsuits or flagging jumpsuits as swimsuits
   - A category is being flagged as swimwear when it represents just shorts.  Example: **Men > Clothing > Shorts & Swimwear > Shorts**
   - Situations where there are no spaces between substrings.  Example:  where the description **Layette/Infant Unisex - Accessories – Sale** is not being flagged as baby when it contains the word infant

Below is my current code, sample data, and my desired output.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE category_flags
(
category_description VARCHAR(80)
);
 INSERT INTO category_flags 
    (category_description) 
VALUES 

("Baby > Basics > Accessories > Hats,Scarves, & Gloves")
("Men > Shoes & Accessories > Hats")
("Men > Shoes & Accessories > Ties")
("Women > Clothing > Jackets")
("Women > Shoes & Accessories > Hats")
("Kids > Boys > Jackets")
("Tall/Men/Outerwear/Cloth/Sale")
("Men > Bottoms > Swim")
("Men > Bottoms > Swimwear")
("US/Big_Tall/Men/Chinos/Flat_Front")
("men>clothing>sweatshirts")
("men>clothing>swimwear")
("Children/Girls/Outfit")
("Men > Accessories > Fragrance")
("Black_Top/Men/Dress_Shirts/Slim_Fit/Sale")
("Men > Bottoms > Suits, Sport Coats & Trousers")
("Women > Tops > Sweaters")
("Kids > Accessories > Boy's Accessories > Bags")
("boys>accessories>socks")
("Blue_Look/Women/Pants/Sale")
("women > Clothing/Knits/> Jackets")
("Women > Clothing > Jackets")
("Women > Shoes & Accessories > Hats")
("Women > Clothing > Jackets")
("Dresswear/Women  > Belts")
("clothing > men >shorts & swim trunks > swimtrunks")
("Men > Clothing > Shorts & Swimwear > Shorts")
("men>clothing>swimsuits")
("boys>accessories>socks")
("Layette/Infant Unisex - Accessories")
("Layette/Infant Unisex - Accessories - Sale")
("Basics > Baby Boy & Girl> Accessories > Hats,Scarves, & Gloves")
("Women/Clothing & Shoes/Swimwear")
("Evening/Men > Shoes & Accessories > Ties")
("Summer/Child/Jumpers")
("women/fall/clothing & accessories/jumpsuits")
("Women/Clothing & Swimwear/Skirts")
);
```

Current script:

```
select
category_description,
case when regexp_like(category_description, '(.[^o]|[^w]o)men|^men','i')    
and not regexp_like(category_description, 'accessories|hats|bags|belts|shoes|socks|ties' ,'i')   then 1 else 0 end as Mens_Apparel, 

case when regexp_like(category_description, '(.[^o]|[^w]o)men|^men','i')    
and  regexp_like(category_description, 'accessories|hats|bags|belts|shoes|socks|ties' ,'i')   then 1 else 0 end as Mens_Accessories,


case when regexp_like (category_description, 'women','i')   
and not regexp_like(category_description, 'accessories|hats|bags|belts|shoes|socks|ties' ,'i')    then 1 else 0 end as Womens_Apprarel, 

case when regexp_like (category_description, 'women','i')   
and  regexp_like(category_description, 'accessories|hats|bags|belts|shoes|socks|ties' ,'i')    then 1 else 0 end as Womens_Accessories , 


case when regexp_like (category_description, 'boys?|girls?|junior|child(ren)?|kids?','i') 
and not   regexp_like (category_description,'infant|babys?|hidden|womens?|mens?|gift cards?|test','i') then 1 else 0 end as Kids_Products   ,


case when regexp_like(category_description,'toddler|infant|babys?|','i')
and not   regexp_like (category_description,'hidden|womens|mens|^gift cards','i') then 1 else 0 end as Baby_Products,

case when  regexp_like(category_description, '(.[^o]|[^w]o)men|^men','i')  
    and regexp_like(category_description,'swim(wear)?|swim(suit)?','i')then 1 else 0 end as     Mens_Swimwear    ,

case when  regexp_like(category_description,'womens','i') 
and regexp_like(category_description,'(swim(wear|suits))','i') then 1 else 0 end as     Womens_Swimwear   

from category_flags
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Just FYI: n-dru's answer, and the accepted answer, in the thread you mention do the job right, since they match a string containing `woman` ([accepted answer demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJbV8u/1/), [n-dru's](https://regex101.com/r/VJbV8u/2)). Use [G. Linoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30978780/3832970) approach.